# HTMLHelper<dynamic> does not contain a definition for 'Kendo' - Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, html-helper

Getting below error when trying to run the app - have checked solutions online including below but to no avail :-

[MVC Kendo - 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463501/mvc-kendo-system-web-mvc-htmlhelperdynamic-could-be-found)

https://www.telerik.com/forums/compiler-error-message-cs1061-'htmlhelper-dynamic-'-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-'kendo'

Please see attached - any pointers appreciated[image]

Comment: Can you confirm which Web.config file you added the Kendo.Mvc.UI namespace to?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I didn't have Telerik in my Program Files - I downloaded Telerik Controls on to my laptop and added the new Kendo dll as a reference, the error disappeared.